# attempted to assign to readonly property react native error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following (toggle) function:

```
toggleMenu = () => {
    const toValue = this.open ? 0 : 1;
    Animated.spring(this.animation, {
      toValue,
      friction: 5,
    }).start();
    this.open = !this.open;
  };
```

I'm getting an "Attempted to assign to readonly property" error. Can someone explain why this is, and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: use double == to compare or === if use strict
at this place const toValue = this.open ? 0 : 1;

Comment: @ThinkTank `this.open ? 0 : 1` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), that part of the code is fine.. the problem seems to be somewhere outside of this code snippet

Comment: @Bayraa if you are using TypeScript, look for type definitions like `readonly open: boolean` or `ReadOnly<...>` for any of the props of the value assigned to `this.animation` (and remove the readonly constrain to fix the error)...

Comment: try to replace const with var